# Shortcut to close all tabs except pinned one in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm wondering if Eclipse has any shortcut to close all tabs except the pinned one. I use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut every day to close current tabs but it closes all the tabs no matter they were pinned or not. Do Eclipse have any settings for this shortcut to close only not pinned tabs, or does exist another shortcut to achieve such result?

Edit:
I forgot mention I use Eclipse Indigo.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and you will get the `Switch to Editor` view as shown below.

[image: Switch to Editor View]

Now use the keys <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> to select the tab which you want to stay opened and press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key two times so that the button `Invert Selection` is focused. Then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and two times <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. Hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key again to close all other tabs in editor.

Comment: Instead of "two tabs + enter" two times, you could do alt + i and alt + c.

Answer (score 10):

If you right click on your window there is an option "close others" it should work for you,
If you want a shortcut for it its simple to create one, go to >Window > Preferences > General > Keys , search for "close others" then in the Binding filed enter any shortcut key you want, and in the when dropdown; select "In Windows", then apply, OK , Finish.

Comment: I already know about this option, but it still closes pinned tabs. It doesn't close only the current tab which is not sufficient for me. +1 for you :)

Comment: What do you mean pinned tabs?

Comment: Maybe I've used the wrong word - I mean editor. On the top bar you probably have a button with "Pin the current editor" tooltip. You can pin editors so they wouldn't be closed if you reach the limit of the opened editors (General->Editors->Number of opened editors before closing).